# how to prevent in-app purchase hacks in iOS 11? If any

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

i am working on a game application.Users have to purchase a ticket to play game with in-app purchase functionality.

I found that in-app purchase hacking issues before 4-5 years but apple somehow manages to prevent hacks.

so, it is also possible to hack in-app purchase in iOS 10 or later in jailbroken devices?

is there only one way to validating purchase receipt on server side or is there are some other ways to prevent hacking in-app purchase.?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent in-app purchases hacks is, as you said, to **validate the receipt server side**. That's what all big apps/games do. Without this, it's still possible to spoof in-app purchases, even in iOS 11 (on a jailbroken device of course).

iOS Code reference : [Validating Receipts With the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html)

A good tutorial to start with (PHP and Swift code) : [Receipt Validation in Swift](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-receipt-validation-in-swift/)

Comment: Can you prefer some Github code which is available in both iOS and PHP side which validating receipt?

Comment: @user3202457 I think this tutorial http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-receipt-validation-in-swift is a good start to understand receipt validation, with Swift code and PHP

Comment: iOS code reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: @PoojaGupta Thanks, i've added it to the answer :)